# Is it safe to use ERC223 Tokens?

Tags: tokens, erc-20, erc-223

**ERC20** Tokens are currently used in more than **90%** percent of new tokens.

At this point, **is it a good idea** to use instead [ERC223](https://github.com/Dexaran/ERC23-tokens/tree/Recommended), or should be test it further?

*Any real example of ERC223?*

Comment: Related (possible dupe): [What is the latest secure and compatible token standard?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/23885/what-is-the-latest-secure-and-compatible-token-standard)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ERC-223 is a proposal right now, not a standard. See the [proposal discussion](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/223). There are several concerns brought up, including that a new proposal should involve a round-table with more ERC-20 authors to collect feedback.

[ERC-20](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/20) is the standard to follow for new tokens.